# Opening webpage in default browser with double-quotes (") inside url

Tags: delphi, winapi, browser, delphi-7

When I try to open any site that has double-quotes (`"`) inside the link , for ex. `user.php?name="stackoverflow"` it just cuts `"` or sometimes it redirects me to Google!?
Used code:

```
ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar('open'), PChar(URL), nil, SW_SHOW) ;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need use a fully qualified `URL` including the `http://` and escape/encode the `URL` by replacing the double-quotes (`"`) with `%22`.

Also you are passing wrong parameters.

See MSDN: [Use ShellExecute to launch the default Web browser](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224816)

Example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  URL: string;
begin
  URL := 'http://www.user.com/?name="stackoverflow"';
  URL := StringReplace(URL, '"', '%22', [rfReplaceAll]);
  ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar(URL), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

You should always encode the URL parameters, not only double-quotes. You can use Indy with `TIdURI.URLEncode` - `IdURI` unit.
You could also use `HTTPEncode` from the `HTTPApp` unit to encode each parameter in the `URL`.

Note that `TIdURI.URLEncode` will encode the `?` and the `&` separators also. so I think it's a better idea to encode each parameter separately with `HTTPEncode` e.g:

```
URL := 'http://www.user.com/?param1=%s&param2=%s';
URL := Format(URL, [
  HTTPEncode('"stackoverflow.com"'),
  HTTPEncode('hello word!')]);
// output: http://www.user.com/?param1=%22stackoverflow.com%22&param2=hello+word!
```

Comment: +1, but it's much better to use Indy's `URLEncode` (forget which unit, and don't have D7 here to check), which will properly handle all values and not just quotes (like spaces, `&`, and so forth). It's in IdURI.pas in D2007 (Indy 9).

Comment: <g> Thanks Ken, I was just editing the answer with the remark about Indy `URLEncode`. I remember that there is another unit that does that. I am looking in the D7 source folder but cant find it... :/

Comment: @KenWhite, BTW `TIdURI.URLEncode` will encode the `?` and the '&` separators also. so I think it's a better idea to encode each parameter separately with `HTTPEncode`.

Comment: Might be; I haven't used it for a while (not doing anything currently that needs it - mostly SFTP/PGP stuff, which doesn't). I think it might still resolve correctly, though; can't test it right now, though (and don't really need to know now, either <g>).

Comment: Please note that under Delphi 10.2 (Tokyo) this will execute nothing. However, the code will work if executed outside debugger!