# ShellExecute is opening the default browser but not loading the URL

Tags: windows

I have this line of code :

```
ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar('https://www.youtube.com/'), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

it works perfectly fine but not in 1 computer. It just open the default browser(*UC*) and loads the default web page(*www.uc123.com*).
Also if I press **Window+R** then type **www.youtube.com** the result is the same. 
I'm suspecting I'm missing a windows configuration stuff because of the 10 computers I tested only 1 computer it does not work.
**OS is Windows10 chinese, guest mode.**

Comment: I just tried `https://www.youtube.com/` and the result is the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening webpage in default browser with double-quotes (") inside url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154543/opening-webpage-in-default-browser-with-double-quotes-inside-url)

Comment: @kobik You have answer this question before :)

Comment: `https://www.youtube.com/` doesn't have quotes

Comment: Could this behavior be related to the fact that [in China Youtube is blocked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websites_blocked_in_mainland_China)?

Comment: no.. I found the problem, its the UC browser itself. It worked well if the `default brower` is chrome, firefox, IE, Edge and 360. It took me a while to point the problem because the user would not lend me his laptop. he just let me test in VM.

Comment: That's precisely what I assumed right off the bat, by instinct. First of all, I've never heard of that browser. Second of all, you said out of 10 computers, this is the only one which didn't work, with this particular unfamiliar browser.  So there is no code problem here. The problem is it seems this browser doesn't support launching URLs through a command line. What happens when you use any other software which is supposed to open the default browser to a webpage?

Comment: I just installed it and did a test. Using the command line, I called `UCBrowser.exe "www.youtube.com"` and it opened just fine. Also worked fine when calling `UCBrowser.exe www.youtube.com`. I'm reluctant to set it as my default to test though.

Comment: Nothing to do with delphi

Comment: @JerryDodge I believe your tests are equivalent to using the 4th parameter in ShellExecute (i.e. `lpParameters`), whereas code uses `lpFile`. You _might_ be able to perform an equivalent test using "Open with…" on a URL link.

Comment: @Craig The context menu doesn't appear to allow `Open with...` for URL shortcuts...

Comment: `'open'` should be changed to `nil`. Calling `ShellExecute` with a `nil` verb executes the default action registered for the extension/url, which is not always `'open'`, but `'open'` will be attempted if there is no default action registered. Perhaps the browser in question has a malformed command for the `'open'` verb and that is why the URL is not opened.